# Why match_phrase_prefix not matching city name is it too short?

Tags: elasticsearch

Lets say I want to search for "Los Angeles" in database of cities.

Why following query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match_phrase_prefix": {
      "city": {
        "query": "los an",
        "max_expansions": 20,
        "fuzziness": "AUTO"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

is not matching "Lost angeles" but if I change `query` to `query: los ang` it matches "Los angeles" just fine.

Field is mapped just as string with default analyzer

```
"city": {
  "type": "string"
},
```

I want to implement an autocompletion feature and it would be nice to match "los", "los a" and "los an" as well.

**Edit:** I need to clarify, that in case of `los an` I have empty result set, while `los ang` returns total of 9338 results. In first case, I would expect for at least some hits (got over 2 million documents) and not an empty result set. Why is such thing happening?

Comment: Works for me. Tested with ES 2.3.1.

Comment: try increasing the `max_expansions` to higher value to 300 or so and  check if that helps

Comment: @AndreiStefan that is really wierd. I have just added clarification as edit.

Comment: Try @keety's suggestion with increasing the `max_expansions`.

Comment: @AndreiStefan that indeed starts to return some results (with "los angeles" as well) but this is counterproductive as query time increeses from 3 to 150 ms